# how to import a dmp table from oracle to mysql?

Tags: mysql, oracle, dmp

So i have a low of dmp files that were to make tables in my sql developer database is there a way I could use those same dump files for my mysql database tables?

Answer (score 0):

I never did that, but Googling around I found out that there are tools that make it possible. T

> OraDump-to-MySQL is a program to export data from Oracle dump files into MySQL, MariaDB or Percona database. The program does direct reading from the dump, so Oracle installation is not required. Command line support allows to script, automate and schedule the conversion process.

I'm not posting a link (so that someone wouldn't call it *spamming*); I guess you'll be able to find it yourself.